# database filesystem backup error

Tags: postgresql

I get this error earch time:

```
postgres=# select pg_stop_backup();
NOTICE:  pg_stop_backup cleanup done, waiting for required WAL segments to be archived
WARNING:  pg_stop_backup still waiting for all required WAL segments to be archived (60 seconds elapsed)
HINT:  Check that your archive_command is executing properly.  pg_stop_backup can be canceled safely, but the database backup will not be usable without all the WAL segments.
```

These are the steps I have done:

1. made sure postgresql is running
2. connected to postgres server by

   ```
   [root@localhost pgsql]# pgsql postgres postgres
   then
   [root@localhost pgsql]# psql postgres postgres
   psql (9.3.4)
   Type "help" for help.
   ```
3. next:

   ```
   postgres=# select pg_start_backup('varlibpgsql', true);
   pg_start_backup 
   -----------------
   0/F5000028
   (1 row)
   ```
4. Then in separate terminal (as root) I:

   ```
     tar cfP /var/lib/pgsql/db_files_backup4me.tar /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data --exclude "/pg_log"
    (I excluded the pg_log folder as I kept getting errors  
    tar: /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_log/postgresql-Tue.log: file changed as we read it
    tar: /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_stat_tmp: file changed as we read it  )
   ```
5. Next, after successfully creating the tar, I execute in the postgres terminal:

   ```
    postgres=# select pg_stop_backup();
   ```

This is where I get the errors mentioned at the top.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Did you check that your archive_command is executing properly?  Was it?

Comment: Examine the PostgreSQL log files.

Comment: jjanes -  Thanks!  I looked at the archive command and found it worked better after removing the # from the frount of it!